# Installation fails due to clean URLs

Tags: 8, installation, uri

I have a Drupal 8.0.1 installation running under Apache 3.4 from /var/www. During installation, I cannot seem to pass the requirements for clean URLs. I've read through answers I've found on Drupal.org, but to no avail.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! We cannot help you without what you tried without success: We would end up with writing the full documentation here, or try guessing what you could have done wrong. This site is not for guessing, not for giving suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rewrite engine is required to use clean url and you need to intall on terminal by execute the below command.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Comment: And ```service apache2 restart```

Comment: It could be, but in this case I would wonder which answers the OP read on drupal.org, if he didn't find out the Apache Rewrite Engine is required for clean URLs to work.

Comment: thanks for your responce! sudo a2enmod rewrite is the first think I'dove but still not working...

Comment: so still same error is there or any other error do you face?